# How to add a class in ms-coco dataset?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, dataset, mscoco

I have a question. How to add a class in ms-coco dataset?

I tried to learn Mask-Rcnn, I need to add new class in dataset.
But, I don't know how to add, not lose previous dataset.

plz help me

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the config settings where you should put 82 (if you add one class only) like this:

```
    # Number of classes (including background)
    NUM_CLASSES =1 + 80 +1  # Background + Coco + new class name
```